# Design for Users-Challenges Relationship in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, database-design

I am just starting off with app development and am currently writing an Android application which has registered users and a list of 'challenges' which they are able to select and later mark as completed/failed.
The plan is to eventually store all users/challenge/etc data on a database though I haven't implemented this yet.

The issue I have run in to is this - in my current design each User has list variables containing their current challenges and completed challenges eg. two ArrayList fields. 
Users currently select challenges from a listview of different Challenge objects, which are then added to the user's CurrentChallenges list.

What I had not accounted for is how to structure this so that when a user takes on a challenge, they have their own unique copy of that challenge that can be independently marked as completed etc, whereas at the minute every user that selects say, Challenge 1, is simply adding the same challenge with the same ID etc. as each other user that selects Challenge 1.

I supposed I could have each different challenge be its own sub-class of Challenge and assign every user which selects that challenge type a different instance of that class, however this seems like it would be a very messy/inefficient method as all the different classes would be largely the same.

Does anyone have any good ideas or design patterns for this case? Preferably a solution that will be compatible with later storing these challenges in a database and presumably using ORM.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions,
E

Comment: That is how it's currently set up so maybe I've misunderstood it and am okay after all. I was thinking that this would mean the challenge has a single isCompleted value as opposed to having one per user copy of the challenge .

Answer (score 1):

I'd move every aspect of a challenge that is different for each user into a new `Attempt` class. So `Challenge` might have variables for `name`, `description` etc. and `Attempt` would have `inProgress`, `completed` etc. Obviously these are just examples, replace them with whatever data you're actually storing.

Now in your `User` class, you can record challenges using a `Map`. Make it a `Map<Challenge, Attempt>` and each `User` will be able to store an `Attempt` for each `Challenge` to record their progress. The `Challenge` instances are shared between users but there is an `Attempt` instance for each combination of `User` and `Challenge`.

---

When you implement the database later, `Challenge`, `User` and `Attempt` would each translate to a table. `Attempt` would have foreign keys for both of the other tables. Unfortunately I haven't used ORMs much so I'm not sure whether they'd work with a `Map` correctly.

Comment: This definitely seems like a potential solution, I will look in to using maps, thanks for your suggestion.